# vlc command line: -vv and -vvv give zero detail

Tags: vlc

I am chasing a command line vlc conversion (mp4 and wav to mp3) . The problem is that vlc creates a zero byte output file.

I have tried the -vv and -vvv options, hoping vlc would give me a hint about what is going on, but the presence of these switches does nothing.

How to get some hints from vlc?

Example command line:

```
vlc.exe -I -vvv dummy "c:\temp\test\arc\test.aac" --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=48,channels=2,samplerate=192000}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst="C:\data\personal\test\cardbuilding\audio-files\hinative\test2.mp3"}  vlc://quit
```

Comment: `vlc -H` should be exhaustive.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thanks!  -H is to see what options are available. My issue is that I can't figure out how to get any useful info from vlc about what is going wrong.  Also, OP enhanced

Comment: Ooops! Too literal? I take it, you've tried `vlc --file-logging --logfile abc.txt --log-verbose 3
` where 3 = Debug

Comment: @RolfofSaxony No, did not find that option within the five million cmd line options that vlc has. Thank you for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

OK, found out how to get detailed logging for VLC when it runs from a command line.

1. Open VLC interactively
2. Tools | Preferences | All (radio at bottom)
3. Advanced | Logger
4. Turn on logging, set file, set detail level
5. Close VLC
6. Now when you use the vlc.exe command line, you will get a log.

Alternate method (better, as all control remains on the cmd line, but not yet tested by me):

```
vlc --file-logging --logfile abc.txt --log-verbose 3
```

(where 3 = Debug)

That is the good news.

The bad news is... at least in my case, the logged information is not helping me figure out the problem.